# DateTimePicker on .Net Compact Framework - Is it possible to edit the year using the popup keypad?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, datetimepicker

I'm working on an windows mobile application built using c#/dotNet in visual studio. There is a form with a DateTimePicker control. I can use the popup keypad to edit the day and month but it doesn't work for the year.

Has anyone else had this problem? Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried making a new clean Windows Mobile application? I just made a test app and tried your scenario and it worked for me perfectly. I was able to edit all parts of the datetimepicker.

I test using the left, right, up, down characters of the input panel, and the number keys as well. Everything checked out for me.

A new app should give you a good test case to check against.

Comment: Right you are, it must be a problem in my app. Should have checked that myself. Cheers!

Now I just need to track down the problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

After doing some testing on a clean windows mobile project (thanks CJCraft.com) I've found that changing the date format to short instead of long causes this problem. Similar problem with custom formats, anything with yyyy can be edited with the keypad but if shortened to yy it doesn't work anymore.